# How to populate angular material dropdown with user value in database?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

The code that I've written so far populates for input fields but does not populate the dropdown in a reactive form.

user.component.ts:

```
onSelect(user: User): void {
    this.draw.toggle();
    this.userForm.reset({
      displayName: user.displayName, // input field that works
      email: user.email, // input field that works
      roleTitle: user.roleTitle // This is what is not working with the dropdown
    });
  }
```

EDIT:

user.model.ts:

```
export interface User {
    email?: string;
    displayName?: string;
    roleTitle?: string;
}
```

user.component.html:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input id="name" matInput placeholder="Name" type="text" formControlName="displayName">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
    <input id="email" matInput placeholder="E-mail" type="text" formControlName="email">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-select placeholder="Role" formControlName="role">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.value">{{role.displayName}}</mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Add your markup, add user object values, this is not even close enough to help you

Comment: Still not enough detail to help. None of your code shows what you are doing to populate 'roles' for the select component or when that takes place.

Comment: Your `formControlName` should be `roleTitle`, not `role`, for start.

Answer (score 0):

There's missing information but perhaps this helps.

My html

```
<mat-form-field class="form-full-width">
   <mat-select placeholder="Currency" formControlName="currency" name="currency">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let currency of currencies" [value]="currency.value">
           {{currency.viewValue}}
       </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   <mat-hint align="end">Here's the dropdown arrow ^</mat-hint>
 </mat-form-field>
```

The dropdown values in the ts

```
selectedCurrency: string;

currencies = [
    { value: 'EUR', viewValue: 'EUR' },
    { value: 'GBP', viewValue: 'GBP' }
];
```

I get the content of the form in the ts

```
private getContentForm() {
    const formModel = this.customerForm.value;
    this.selectedCurrency = formModel.currency;

    return {
        currency: this.selectedCurrency,
    // rest removed for readability
    };
}
```

Then assign the content of the form to a variable to add the new customer

```
save() {
    if (this.customerForm.valid) {
        const formModel = this.customerForm.value;

        if (!this.form.submitted) {
            // Causes validation to update.
            this.form.onSubmit(null);
            return;
        }

        if (!this.customerForm.valid) {
            this.alertService.showValidationError();
            return;
        }

    }

    this.isSaving = true;
    this.alertService.startLoadingMessage("Saving changes...");

    const addCustomer = this.getContentForm();

    this.customerService.newCustomer(addCustomer).subscribe(
            customer => this.saveCompleted(customer),
            error => this.saveFailed(error));
}
```